# Does anyone know of a feature filled forum package for Umbraco 4.03?

Tags: forum, umbraco

I was wondering if anyone has built or know of a decent forum package for Umbraco 4.03??

I've had a little play with this but its a bit basic

http://our.umbraco.org/projects/umbraco-forum-package

and

http://our.umbraco.org/projects/uforum-basics

I've found this article on how to integrate YAF forum but would rather have one which fits a bit better..

http://dawoe.blogspot.com/2009/02/intergrate-yet-another-forum-193rc2.html

Of course I know one answer, write or extend one of the above :) Any help would be gratefully received.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

uForum is used to power the Our Umbraco community - so that's the current recommended forum package.

YAF is a fully-featured forum/bulletin-board web-application, which can be integrated with Umbraco (using an ASP.NET Membership Provider).  Aside from that YAF is standalone.

Update: There is a new package called [nForum](http://our.umbraco.org/projects/website-utilities/nforum).

Answer (score 0):

I guess it depends on your requirements.

What features are lacking, clearly you know what you want so any guidance on what the forum should include will help.

Pretty much any asp.net based forum software would work with Umbraco. I guess the main thing would be the integration with the Membership provider in Umbraco. In this case Any forum software that could use a custom ASP.NET membership provider would integrate pretty much seamlessly.

There are plenty of opensource and commercial forum packages available for ASP.NET, just find one that matches your requirements and look at integrating it or running it alongside Umbraco.

Comment: Yep YAF being one of them :) If I had time I would write one!! Might be worth waiting to Umbraco 5 comes out and then hook up an mvc project.