# how can i make a forum and used umbraco search option in umbraco?

Tags: search, full-text-search, search-engine, umbraco, forum

I need to make a forum in my website and Set a search engine with Umbraco tools.
I need some video links and e-books.

this [link](http://umbraco.com/assets/umbracotv/designer/razorcookbook/ep7_search.flv) is very useful but i need more documents and video.
I want to implement search in Umbraco. I found videos on umbraco.org/.../adding-a-search-to-your-website but its only 2 minutes long. I know if i pay the 19 euros i can watch the whole video, but i live in Iran and i can't pay for it.

Update:
this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2297009/does-anyone-know-of-a-feature-filled-forum-package-for-umbraco-4-03) is related.(forum)
this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14333732/make-a-optional-search-in-umbraco/14335513#14335513) is related.(search)

Comment: http://umbraco.com/assets/umbracotv/designer/razorcookbook/ep7_search.flv

Comment: +1 for the feedback to community

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[nForum](http://our.umbraco.org/projects/website-utilities/nforum) seems promising.

Also, since [yaf](http://www.yetanotherforum.net) is a user control, you can integrate it in umbraco as well. But you'll need to do some work to get it working. A walkthrough is explained [here](http://www.createsoft.co.uk/blog/2008/10/yaf-integration-to-umbraco-4/).