# Make a optional search in umbraco

Tags: asp.net, search, umbraco, umbraco5

I made new document type in umbraco.then made some node by this document type in content.
i will set up a new search index so found this code that Setting up a new search index.

```
@* Get the search term from query string *@
@{var searchTerm = Request.QueryString["search"];}
@{var results = ExamineManager.Instance.Search(searchTerm, true); }
```

but i do not know how to limited this code that can search only in my document type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are couple of steps for this.

You will have to:

- Create a `ISearchCriteria` object;
- Create an search expression from the criteria object, including the docType alias as a field to be searched;
- Search using the expression.

This can be coded as:

```
var criteria = ExamineManager.Instance.CreateSearchCriteria();

var expression = criteria.Field("nodeTypeAlias", "yourDocTypeAlias")
                         .And()
                         .Field("nodeName", searchTerm);

var results = ExamineManager.Instance.Search(expression.Compile());
```

This is possible because when Umbraco publishes a node, it saves the node's docType alias to the search index.

There is more [Examine documentation here](http://examine.codeplex.com/documentation). I would also recommend downloading [Luke](http://code.google.com/p/luke/) which is a standalone tool that will allow you to look inside an index so you can see what is actually stored by Umbraco.